# JBOSS libraries not in Classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, classpath

in our web app uses some libraries located under /client in the JBOSS directory. In Windows these libraries are detected correctly, so there's no error when compiling. However, in Linux isn't the same. Libraries are not detected, so I'm not able to compile the web application.

note: we're using JBOSS AS + eclipse for a Spring MVC app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Buildpath window select the Libraries Tab. The click on add library. Select Server Runtime and choose your server instance.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some confusion here but more details are needed.

Separate the JBoss Application Server (AS) from the client completely (do not share ANY libraries between projects and on classpath in IDE and between client/server components).

Then try (best-practice) bundling *server* application-specific libraries inside the EAR/WAR for the server software. Then, separately, bundle the *client* libraries in their own JAR/s. Then include those client JAR/s in the CLASSPATH when running the client software.

That should make clear what is or isn't being found/where and ensure that when deployed in real-world use, there is not some assumption by the client to somehow find the server libraries (which in reality are likely to be on a different host entirely).

Comment: I share your point of view, but this is an app we inherited from our client, and we can't make that kind of changes from the time being.

Comment: The client and server libraries must be separated for a client/server application to work with any reliability, assuming running on different hosts. For now even try copying them into different directories with different classpaths for server and client to at least find where the problem lies.